# MailChimp Submit Button CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mailchimp, submit-button

community,

I have a question regarding the CSS styling of MailChimp's "Submit"-Button. So far I managed to change the colour and font of my button using CSS.

I wanted to change the padding and margin of my Submit button, but after trying different "margin/padding"-combinations and just experimenting inside Google Chrome's DevTools I cannot find a solution to this: It seems like the button is cut off if I increase the padding.

Screenshot 1 is how it looks right now, screenshot 2 is what happens if I increase the top/bottom-padding from 0 to 20px.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2 - changed padding in Goolge DevTools]

This is what I used in my Custom-CSS to change the font, colour etc:

```
    #mc_embed_signup .button {
    background-color: #d1e5e6  !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    font: 16px, bebas_neue, Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    padding-left: 40px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
    padding-bottom: 13px !important;
    }
```

And this is the HTML for the submit button:

```
    <div style="text-align: center !important;"><input type="submit" value="Abonnieren" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
```

I hope someone out there can help me with this curious issue. I would like that all buttons are the same size (for consistency) but I already struggle with changing the "read more" button for post grids. Hope I can at least adjust the submit button so it doesn't look too off. This one is just too skinny.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove `line-height,height,padding` of `#mc_embed_signup .button` /classic-10_7.css:7

Comment: remove the height otherwise your padding makes it too large for the height.  PS as you know how to inspect elements, you should play with the styles in your window - try ticking unticking the styles to see how it effects the button

Comment: Thank you Mr. X and @Pete. How can I remove the line-height and height if I did not add them? I tried this:

 height: none !important;
 line-height: none !important;

(Yes, again the important's but otherwise it's not displaying...)
Unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue.

Comment: try [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height): auto and [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height): normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the important keyword in #mc_embed_signup .button. The padding-bottom is one of them

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    padding-left: 40px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
    padding-bottom: 13px !important;
}
```

This is why when you set padding-top and padding-bottom the text is cut-off. Simply, the padding-bottom is not applied. You can either git rid of the important keyword, which I strongly recommend, or use the important keyword with additional [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules.

**Edit**

After removing the important keyword, you can set a height for your button as follows

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {
 height: 30px;
}
```

Try to experiment whether you need the !important keyword for it. Try to avoid it as possible

You can also use padding-top and -bottom; for instance as below. Make sure to use auto height. Otherwise, you will need to set uneven values for your paddings; i.e 20 for top and 40 for bottom

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {
   padding-top: 17px;
   padding-bottom: 17px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I used the important keyword because otherwise, the changes weren't visible. Now, I removed the padding-bottom completely and the button is still "thin" (for the lack of a better word).

Comment: I think I am not able to see padding-bottom !important for #mc_embed_signup .button in the website anymore, did you remove it?

Comment: HI @orabis,
thank you! I had to use the !important but setting the padding-top and padding-bottom worked now. I'm not sure if I got the exact same size as my other buttons but at least it looks like that. 
I will have to look into all these things more closely as I'm always stuck with these issues for hours!

Thanks to everyone else who answered so quickly as well, I should've asked this question sooner, would've saved me a lot of time. :))

Answer (score 2):

Update addition css with this:

```
#mc_embed_signup .button {
    height: 45px !important;
}
```